# Android set custom adapter string array size in thread

Tags: java, android, listview

I am trying to set array length from database I am getting this error:

```
EE/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.cekmekoytipmerkezi.diyetisyen.diyetisyen, PID: 11676
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cekmekoytipmerkezi.diyetisyen.diyetisyen/com.cekmekoytipmerkezi.diyetisyen.diyetisyen.DiyetisyenActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3253)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
                  at com.cekmekoytipmerkezi.diyetisyen.diyetisyen.AkisArrayAdapter.getCount(AkisArrayAdapter.java:47)
                  at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:508)
                  at com.cekmekoytipmerkezi.diyetisyen.diyetisyen.AkisFragment.onCreateView(AkisFragment.java:136)
                  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
                  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:339)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:601)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1265)
                  at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6915)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3216)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Basically I have a listview which I need to populate from my database. I have created a custom adapter. At my fragment when I set the `String[] ogunler = new String[10];` at the initial declaration and don't do anything in the thread I receive the data but I have a bunch of empty list items after the actual data.

My fragment code:

```
public class AkisFragment extends Fragment
{
    String[] ogunler;
    int hastaID;
    String dayOfTheWeek;
    int programID;
    AkisArrayAdapter adapter;

    public AkisFragment()
    {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_akis, container, false);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        final int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        String SQL = "SELECT email, sifre, ID FROM Hasta WHERE Hasta.email = '";
        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        if (bundle != null)
        {
            hastaID = bundle.getInt("hastaID");
        }

        ...

        new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
                    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(getResources().getString(R.string.db_connection));
                    dayOfTheWeek = "Pazartesi";
                    String SQL = "SELECT ID FROM Program Where hastaID = " + Integer.toString(hastaID) + "AND gun = '" + dayOfTheWeek + "'";
                    Log.w(dayOfTheWeek, "123");
                    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);
                    int counter = 0;
                    while (rs.next())
                    {
                        programID = rs.getInt(1);
                    }
                    String SQLcounter = "SELECT ID FROM Program Where hastaID = " + Integer.toString(hastaID) + "AND gun = '" + dayOfTheWeek + "'";
                    Statement stmtCounter = conn.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rsCounter = stmtCounter.executeQuery(SQLcounter);
                    int arrSize = 0;
                    while(rsCounter.next())
                    {
                        arrSize++;
                    }
                    ogunler = new String[arrSize];

                    SQL = "SELECT ogunTipi, ogunIcerik FROM Ogun WHERE programID = " + Integer.toString(programID);
                    Statement stmt2 = conn.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs2 = stmt2.executeQuery(SQL);
                    int counter2 = 0;

                    while (rs2.next())
                    {
                        ogunler[counter2] = rs2.getString(2) + " " + rs2.getString(1);
                        //Log.w(ogunler[counter2], "123");
                        counter2++;
                    }
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                    {
                        public void run()
                        {
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    });
                    conn.close();
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SQLException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();


        ListView list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvAkis);
        adapter = new AkisArrayAdapter(getActivity(), ogunler);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        return view;
    }
}
```

The Custom Adapter:

```
public class AkisArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    String items[];
    int programID;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public AkisArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] _items)
    {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.items = _items;
    }



    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return items.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.aks_list_item, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvOgun);
            holder.iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivOgun);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.tv.setText(items[position]);
        if (holder.tv.getText().toString().endsWith("Ana Öğün"))
        {
            holder.iv.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ana);
        }
        else if (holder.tv.getText().toString().endsWith("Ara Öğün"))
        {
            holder.iv.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ara);
        }
        else if (holder.tv.getText().toString().endsWith("Ek Öğün"))
        {
            holder.iv.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ek);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder
    {
        ImageView iv;
        TextView tv;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *What am I doing wrong?*  ...  [You didn't learn java's basics](http://ideone.com/QCtO0g) ... BaseAdapter.items does know nothing about `ogunler` as at the point when you asign it it was null ...

Comment: Java's basics also says: You can't resize an array in Java. ... so obvious choice is some other containar which can be resized ...

Comment: @Selvin BaseAdapter.items does not need to know anything about it since I just need to pass some strings into the listview I have created AkisArrayAdapter. It would have been great if you read the real question. I have also tried to use other containers(Lists). But as stephanmantel said in his answer I am curtain this is a asynchronization issue.

Comment: What? It will be great if you would understand some basics... public int getCount() { return items.length; } and you set items to null in the constructor and never change it again...

Comment: @Selvin I don't know if you read the code and question or not. But in the thread you can see that I am creating an ogunler string and filling it up afterwards. I am still getting an NullPointerException which I know the meaning of I just don't know why I am getting it. I am not saying that I am doing everything right if that would be the case this question would not exist. By replying You didn't learn java's basics you are not helping in any way. If you wanna discuss that this is not the place for it.

Comment: Yes, I did it, is null http://ideone.com/PPHi95

Answer (score 0):

You get your data asyncronously. This means that Android tries to make a view for you, but does not have data yet. So if you would just supply an empty array at first, is would work. Then in a later stadium you can set the results for the adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter.

So first to solve the NullPointerException, the items in the Adapter need an inital value.

```
public class AkisArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    String[] items = {};
    ...
    ...
}
```

Then I suppose you should set the new items to the adapter. So add a setter to the adapter

```
public void setItems(String[] newItems) {
    this.items = newItems;
}
```

I hope I got understood the question, if not, please elaborate, I try to help. (and perhaps gain a few points ;))

Comment: *At my fragment when I set the String[] ogunler = new String[10]; at the initial declaration and don't do anything in the thread I receive the data but I have a bunch of empty list items.* ... so with your "solution" obviously ListView will be empty forever ...

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have created the method: public void setItems(String[] newItems) inside my custom adapter. I also changed String[] items = {}; as you said. I have moved the adapter = new AkisArrayAdapter(getActivity(), ogunler); into the thread and called it after the while loop which fills the content of ogunler string array. Now I am getting a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error within the thread. Here is my final thread: http://pastebin.com/SahHuNfi

Comment: Cool, good to here you solved it. It might be a good idea to post your solution as an answer to your own question and than accept that answer :)

Comment: @stephanmantel oh my problem is not solved. I have no idea why I am still getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Although I have created the String inside the thread.